# How to ensure that sequential api calls don't cause data integrity problems

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs

React -> Node -> Sql

I have to make sequential api calls on a button click.
lets say --
v1/firstApi
v1/secondApi

`Promise.all([axios.post('v1/firstApi), axios.post('v1/secondApi'])`

Now the first api updates a table called table 1 with some data and second api updates a table called table 2 with some other data.

If the first call succeeds and the second call fails. I have a problem of data not being correct in table 2 as intended..

How to approach this problem without trying to rollback the firstApi database update.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?  This is too generic/abstract to be answered on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code so I am guessing you are asking for a generalized solution.

If you really really need to update the data in 2 tables at the same time one thing you can do is merge the database calls in the API and perform a database transaction. This will wither succeed or fail as a whole. So you won't have the problem of inconsistent data.

If You don't have access to the API then I guess you can't do it from your frontend. You have to make another call manually to revert the first table's data

Comment: Let us say that we have to have two different apis, then is there any way of using transactions..That is what I am mainly looking for

Comment: There is a concept called distributed transaction in microservices. You can check that out and see if that fits your need

Comment: Welcome. Hope I could help